# why does return two values in pandas apply does not set the entire row like in one return parameter?

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to return 2 new columns via apply function in pandas , i get 0 and 1 which are the are the headers names in the return data frame , when i get 2  data frames  i get dfata frames with 2 columns  , my code is :

```
import pandas as pd

def sample_apply(x):
    numer_1, numer_2 = x[0], x[1]
    print numer_1/2, numer_2/2
    return numer_1/2, numer_2/2

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': 1,
    'number_1': 10,
    'number_2': 20,
},index=[0])


df['number_1_div_2'],df['number_2_div_2'] = df[['number_1', 'number_2']].apply(sample_apply, axis=1, result_type="expand")

print df
```

prints :

```
   id  number_1  number_2  number_1_div_2  number_2_div_2
0   1        10        20               0               1
```

while this on the other hand :

```
df1 = df[['number_1', 'number_2']].apply(sample_apply, axis=1, result_type="expand")
print df1a
```

prints

```
5 10
```

means that the apply works but the assignment does not work , what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want assign to subset like:

```
df[['number_1_div_2', 'number_2_div_2']] = df[['number_1', 'number_2']].apply(sample_apply, axis=1, result_type="expand")
print (df)
   id  number_1  number_2  number_1_div_2  number_2_div_2
0   1        10        20             5.0            10.0
```